# Calling 'fs` from Next.js Component

Tags: next.js

Okay, so I know what the problem is, what I need help with is a way to solve this.

Here's the hierarchy:

```
Page (SSG)
   --> Head
   --> Layout
      --> Navigation
      --> Page content
```

The page leverages `getStaticPaths` and `getStaticProps`. Both methods use a library file in my `lib` folder. This library file also has a method, let's say `getAllPages`, that returns a tree of pages based on my documentation folder. In order to get that tree, of course, `fs` is used to traverse the file system;

The intention is that my navigation page would show a tree of pages based on what's returned. I'd like to call the `getAllPages` method from my Navigation component, but obviously there's a problem with client-side vs. server-side.

There are two ways I can think about doing this, but I'm not a fan of either:

1. pass data all the way down from the page, through the layout, to the navigation (this seems tightly coupled)
2. create an api endpoint and have my navigation component call the endpoint (this seems like going around your hand to get to your elbow)

Is there a better way to do this?